# best address to place large array using linker script section

Tags: linker

I want to implement fast save / load of my data using a manually managed >2gb buffer of data.
The following seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char myvar[2000000000]  __attribute__ ((section ("MYDATA"))) ;
int main(){ printf("variable location: %p", myvar); }

> gcc static_location2.c -Wl,--section-start=MYDATA=0x900000
> objdump -h a.out 
# variable location: 0x900000
```

Is the location 0x900000 as good as any ? 
Or are there a more preferred address i should use.
also, what would be the equivalent linker script i would use instead of the command line option i use above ? 
also, what would be the analoug using visual studio on windows ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `readelf -S` of your program?